# filcenter not properly working for chapter name in titlesec package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, chapters, titlesec

I want to move the chapter name into exactly **centre** of the page but there is **little Gap in left side** how can i fix it. here is my **titlesec** code

```
\documentclass[9pt,a5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\tab[1][15pt]{\hspace*{#1}} %for \tab space
%=====CHAP. STYLE=======
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\huge\bfseries\scshape\filcenter}
%{\fbox{\itshape\thechapter}}%
{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1cm}
%======================
     |
     |
   [&]
   [so]
   [on]
     |
     |
```

[image: This chapter name is not exactly center]

Comment: `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]...`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `display` rather than `block`:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\huge\bfseries\scshape\filcenter}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}
```

(using a font that has boldface small caps, of course). Most likely, `\scshape` suffices.